# java sendkeys Error keys should be a string

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting an error when trying to pass in a username and password to a form field using `sendKeys`.  Below is my User Class followed by my test class.  Does anyone know why the application is not passing a string?

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: keys should be a string

```
public class User {
    public static String username;
    public static String password;


    public User() {
        this.username = "username";
        this.password = "password";
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

}

@Test
public void starWebDriver()  {
    driver.get(domainURL.getURL());
    WebElement userInputBox, passInputBox;
    userInputBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='email']"));
    passInputBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']"));
    System.out.println("before sending keys");
    userInputBox.sendKeys(User.username);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You're accessing static properties that are never initialized (null) because the constructor is never called.

You can either set the static properties directly or take out the static context and initialize a User in your test.

Ex.

```
public class User {
    public String username;
    public String password;


    public User() {
        this.username = "username";
        this.password = "password";
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

}


@Test
public void starWebDriver()  {
    User user = new User();

    driver.get(domainURL.getURL());
    ...
    userInputBox.sendKeys(user.username);
}
```

Comment: programming advice: I would even consider changing `user.username` to `user.getUsername()` because as OOP approach acessing variable through getter should be safer. Dont ask me why, I am also programming newbie :)

Answer (score 2):

use

```
userInputBox.sendKeys(String.valueOf(user.username));
```